# Internal WLAN broken after kernel and firmware update

Tags: pi-3, wifi

After I did `pacman -Syu` yesterday, the internal WLAN doesn't work any more.

So I plugged in an external USB network device (Realtek) and it worked fine with the same settings. But the internal device starts with failure: "Failed to create interface p2p-dev-p2p-dev-wlan0: -22 (Invalid argument)"

`iwlist wlan0 scan` returns: "wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning: Invalid argument"

Seems there is a firmware file missing (I read, if the Broadcom adapter isn't able to scan for networks, the firmware hasn't loaded). Has anybody got an idea what's missing and where to get it?

My kernel is *4.9.62-1-ARCH #1 SMP Fri Nov 17 13:51:32 UTC 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux*.

The firmware is *linux-firmware-20171009.bf04291-1-any* and *raspberrypi-firmware-20171103-1-any*.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In raspbian Stretch I installed package **firmware-brcm80211** to get internal wlan working (I made Stretch root with debootstrap). Firmware is installed to /lib/firmare/brcm/ so you can check existence of needed firmware(there must to be 29 files). Maybe raspberrypi-firmware-20171103-1-any not contains that. Find similar Arch package.